# How to create a DataTemplate from a path in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, datatemplate

I'm creating a button control for a manual button. With this button machine movements can be triggered. The arrow on the button shows the direction. The arrow is a vector graphic (Shapes.Path) and I want it to tilt based on the given degree. The following code shows my datatemplate and the method in which I want to turn the arrow:

The symbol property which contains the datatemplate and path:

```
<Setter Property="Symbol">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="ArrowTemplate">
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0,0 64,32 0,64 0,48 32,32 0,16 Z" Stretch="Uniform" Width="150" Fill="{DynamicResource ButtonForegroundBrush}" Stroke="{DynamicResource ButtonForegroundBrush}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Path.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The method in which I want to turn the arrow:

```
private void rotateArrow()
{
    if (this.Symbol != null)
    {
        RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform((int)this.ArrowDirection);

        TransformGroup transform = new TransformGroup();
        transform.Children.Add(rotate);

        Path path = (Path)this.Symbol.LoadContent();
        path.RenderTransform = transform;

        // Set the path as datatemplate and set this.Symbol.
    }

}
```

NOTE: this.ArrowDirection is based from an enumerable which contains the degree value for rotating.

If anyone knows how to achieve this or how to do it in a different way I will be very happy since I can't find it anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is your Symbol property a DataTemplate? Why do you have such a property at all? You could directly operate on the Content of the Button, e.g. assign a Path and change the RenderTansform of that Path.

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate the transform in code-behind. The `RotateTransform` has a dependency property `Angle` you should bind to.

Comment: The symbol property is a property defined in the framework I have to use. That property is for an image. Why the  property is there is because the user can make a button with an image and text. I am not the creator of this framework, I only have to work with it.

I'll try binding to angle. It might  be a nice solution.